# How do I convert a 1x1 Eigen::C++ sparse matrix to an integer value?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

This is what I am trying to do, (I have removed the technical part and simplified the problem)

I have predefined these matrices, sequence, u1, u2. They have to be matrices in sparse form.

```
MatrixXi sequence(1,5)
SparseMatrix<int> u1(5,1)
SparseMatrix<int> u2(5,1)
```

Now, I would like to perform sequence(0)=u1'*u2. This is my code.

```
sequence(i)=(((u1.transpose())*u2).coeffRef(0,0))
```

but I get this error

```
[Error] 'const Type' has no member named 'coeffRef'.
```

I know it is because a 1x1 sparse matrix is not equivalent to an integer. How should I approach this? Somehow, I have to convert it to an integer.

Comment: I have tried sequence(0,i)=int((u1.transpose())*Amatrices[i]); to get   [Error] invalid cast from type 'const Type {aka const Eigen::SparseSparseProduct<Eigen::SparseMatrix<int>, const Eigen::SparseMatrix<int>&>}' to type 'int'

Comment: These are not standard library types. Why not tell what library the come from? Or if you have defined them, provide the definitions.

Comment: `u1'` is a 5x1 matrix, `u2`, too. You can't multiply those

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, he mentions it in the title

Comment: I transposed the matrix to multiply them.

Comment: @WorldSEnder: thanks, I rolled back the edit where it was removed.

Comment: what is the code in the overloaded operator `*`  what should it return?

Comment: I am not sure, I am not particular proficient at deciphering libraries, as I only have a rudimentary knowledge of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `(u1.transpose() * u2)` is not actually (by default) a matrix object but rather a `Eigen::SparseSparseProduct`. You can get around this by either assigning it to a temporary variable:

```
u3 = (u1.transpose() * u2);
sequence(0,0) = u3.coeffRef(0,0);
```

or by casting it:

```
sequence(0,0) = (SparseMatrix<int>(u1.transpose() * u2)).coeff(0,0);
```